# Radgrid stop the ability to add new and edit a row at the same time

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid, telerik-grid

On my radgrid I have inline inserting and editing.

It is possible for the user to click "Add New" which gives them an editing template and then to click "edit" on an existing record. This results two editors being visible.

I would like to stop the ability to edit if they are inserting data and likewise to stop the ability to insert if they are editing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely possible - found [this topic](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-switching-insert-add-modes.html) a while ago while searching for the same.

Comment: Subclassed the grid and handled it in the override of OnItemCommand - works fine. P.S. Would you mind posting the code to your answer for future reference incase the link dies?